# How to save an axios request as json object?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am building a web applications with offline capabilities and i want to save the API requests as json in localStorage and make the request when connection is available, i am using axios to make the API requests, so lets say i have this request

```
$axios.post(`/users/`, {username: 'user', password: 'supersecretpassword'})
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {

      });
```

what i want to do is get this request as an object and use that object later to make the request. **is this possible?** **how?**

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage does not allow saving functions, but what you could do is save the request options object and use with a slightly different but documented Axios syntax:

```
var requestParams = {
  method: 'post',
  url: '/users',
  data: {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'supersecret password'
  }
}

axios(requestParams).then(....)
```

You can then decide to keep `requestParams` in localStorage and use it whenever you wish.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a function for this:

```
function getUsers(){
    return $axios.post(`/users/`, {username: 'user', password: 'supersecretpassword'})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });
}
```